# Random online Prediction errors 500 and 429 with Resnet50 on AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I deployed a ResNet50 model (900 MB) on AI Platform, with a minimal node = 1.

When I make inference, sometimes, i get errors 500 and 429 randomly. For AI Platform code errors (https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/troubleshooting):

1. Error 500: Could not load model
2. Error 429: Out of memory

I am a bit confused because these errors happen randomly. When these errors happen, i play again the requests, and after i get good results.

Please, could you explain me why i get this behavior ? And how i can fix this issue ?

Thanks a lot for your answers,

Bests,

Comment: What is your number of requests per second and what server model did you use for serving? Have you confirm you have enough resources ? ```For example to specify a quad core CPU, use the gcloud beta component and add the following optional flag to your command: --machine-type "mls1-c4-m2". For example:

MODEL_VERSION="cpu_v2"

gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $MODEL_VERSION \
 --model $MODEL_NAME \
 --runtime-version 1.14 \
 --python-version 3.5 \
 --framework tensorflow \
 --origin $SAVED_MODEL_PATH_CPU \
 --machine-type "mls1-c4-m2"
```

Comment: 20 requests simultaneously. I used C4 or C1 matchine. I get the same issues.

Comment: Can you post the logs when issue happens? Do you see any correlation in Dashboard in regards CPU/Memory resources and failure.

Comment: Hi, I get this message in log when Error 429 happens:  jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.ml.v1.PredictionLogEntry"   
  message: "Prediction server is out of memory, possibly because model size is too big."   
  numInstances: "1"   
 }

Comment: I get this message in log when Error 500 happens:  jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.ml.v1.PredictionLogEntry"   
  message: "Prediction failed."   
  numInstances: "1"   
 }

Comment: In AI Platform, I don't know how getting nodes status (CPUs, Memory) when prediction failed. Let me know if you have any ideas, thanks !

Comment: You mentioned that you have a 900 MB model, my understanding is that for 250 MB you need to whitelist your project is this already done?. https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/quotas#requesting_a_quota_increase. We have an alpha service in which you can use GPUs and also use different machine type. The full list is available here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types. 

We’re happy to hear from you if we need to enable additional Compute Engine machine types. If you desire a machine type not available here, please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked to GCP support to increase the RAM quota. I don't get answer unitl now. May be this quota will solve my issues.

Comment: Is this working now?